# Custom fields displayed by Grails Fields plugin with <f:display>

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to display some fields using the `<f:display>` tag of the Grails Fields plugin. I tried the following:

```
<f:display bean="user" property="authorities" label="roles"/>
<f:display bean="user" property="username"/>
```

However, this only displays the field values, not the labels. I tried adding a custom template `grails-app/views/_fields/default/_displayWrapper.gsp`

```
<span id="${property}-label" class="property-label">${label}</span>
<div class="property-value" aria-labelledby="${property}-label">${value}</div>
```

This custom template *is* used with

```
<f:table collection="${userList}" except="password"/>
```

But it is ignored when I use `<f:display>`

Answer (score 1):

In your `_displayWrapper` you should use `${widget}` instead of `${value}` as you want the rendering of `_displayWidget` to get the specific types of rendering.

The `<f:table>` is IMO a bit broken, but I'll look into that as soon as I have time. I'm doing a presentation on the Fields plugin at Greach, so I need to do something :-)

Comment: see examples in my code for a fields plugin demo I did: https://github.com/sbglasius/g3-fields-plugin-demo

Comment: I am trying to do someting similar: using <f:display bean="xxx"/> shows all fields except id, dateCreated and lastUpdated. I need to find a way to show id and dateCreated.  The except="[]" and similar doesnt seem to work on f:display, but f:table does allow you to show the ID etc. I would have thought that being able to show id on display is more important than on a table?  I am trying to find a way to show ID with the other fields.  Not had luck yet.

Comment: This is currently a limitation. I suggest you raise an enhancement request on github.